# Deserialise a dynamic JSON into a java object

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, json-deserialization

Is it possible to somehow convert a dynamic JSON object (No fixed schema) into a Java object?

For example, for first time, I can get the following JSON object at runtime:

```json
{
  "addressDetails": {
    "homeAddresses": [
      {
        "houseNo": "1",
        "city": "2"
      }
    ],
    "currentAddress": {
      "houseNo": "1",
      "city": "2"
    }
  },
  "personalDetails": {
    "birthDetails": {
      "birthPlace": "1",
      "birthMonth": "2"
    }
  },
  "confidentialDetails": {
    "birthDetails": {
      "birthPlace": "1",
      "birthMonth": "2"
    }
  },
  "bankingDetails": {
    "bankName": "1",
    "bankAccountNo": 2
  }
}
```

The next time, maybe with something like this:

```json
{
  "confidentialDetails": {
    "birthDetails": {
      "birthPlace": "1",
      "birthMonth": "2"
    }
  },
  "personalDetails": {
    "birthDetails": {
      "birthPlace": "1",
      "birthMonth": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I handle all these variations? Is it possible with Jackson/Gson or some other library?

I expect to find a solution which is very generic and can handle the different variations in JSON object gracefully.

Comment: Are these actually variations? Looks the same minus some missing data.

Comment: You have shown us two examples. You need to explain what the actual variation is.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider -- Assume there are n keys (eg: "confidentialDetails" or "addressDetails") & out of those i can get any k of them with no fixed order . Also, the structure of the value for some keys can be same as it's in 2nd example .

Comment: @tgdavies , replied back to your comment above -- let me know if you still require some more info before you can help

Comment: Jackson will simply ignore missing values and set the relevant properties to null. Try it.

Comment: Both Gson and Jackson shouldn't have any problems with the example as shown (it may need some config to declare that fields can be optional/absent). In the deserialized object, the absent fields will simply be null.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand your question. However, you can try to define all possible JSON objects into one object and then serialize them using GSON or another JSON conversion tool.
like this:

```
public class Parent {
    private AddressDetails addressDetails;
    private PersonalDetails personalDetails;
    private PersonalDetails confidentialDetails;
}
class AddressDetails{
    private List<HomeAddresses> homeAddresses;
    private List<CurrentAddress> currentAddresses;
}
class Addresses{
    private String houseNo;
    private String city;
}
class BirthDetails{
    private String birthDetails;
    private String birthMonth;
}
class HomeAddresses extends Addresses{
}
class CurrentAddress extends Addresses{
}
class PersonalDetails extends BirthDetails{
}
```

Or if there are too many types to define, you can simply convert the JSON string to a JSON object for use
like this:

```
String jsonStr = "{\n" +
            "  \"addressDetails\": {\n" +
            "    \"homeAddresses\": [\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"houseNo\": \"1\",\n" +
            "        \"city\": \"2\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"currentAddress\": {\n" +
            "      \"houseNo\": \"1\",\n" +
            "      \"city\": \"2\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"personalDetails\": {\n" +
            "    \"birthDetails\": {\n" +
            "      \"birthPlace\": \"1\",\n" +
            "      \"birthMonth\": \"2\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"confidentialDetails\": {\n" +
            "    \"birthDetails\": {\n" +
            "      \"birthPlace\": \"1\",\n" +
            "      \"birthMonth\": \"2\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"bankingDetails\": {\n" +
            "    \"bankName\": \"1\",\n" +
            "    \"bankAccountNo\": 2\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONUtil.parseObj(jsonStr);
    JSONObject addressDetails = jsonObject.get("addressDetails", JSONObject.class);
    JSONArray homeAddresses = addressDetails.get("homeAddresses", JSONArray.class);
    JSONObject object = homeAddresses.get(0, JSONObject.class);
    System.out.println(object.get("houseNo"));
    System.out.println(object.get("city"));
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do that with Jackson library. Just read the JSON and remove data with `addressDetails` and `bankingDetails` keys.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        ObjectNode jsonData = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree("{\"addressDetails\":{\"homeAddresses\":[{\"houseNo\":\"1\",\"city\":\"2\"}],\"currentAddress\":{\"houseNo\":\"1\",\"city\":\"2\"}},\"personalDetails\":{\"birthDetails\":{\"birthPlace\":\"1\",\"birthMonth\":\"2\"}},\"confidentialDetails\":{\"birthDetails\":{\"birthPlace\":\"1\",\"birthMonth\":\"2\"}},\"bankingDetails\":{\"bankName\":\"1\",\"bankAccountNo\":2}}");
        jsonData.remove("addressDetails");
        jsonData.remove("bankingDetails");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonData));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```json
{
  "personalDetails" : {
    "birthDetails" : {
      "birthPlace" : "1",
      "birthMonth" : "2"
    }
  },
  "confidentialDetails" : {
    "birthDetails" : {
      "birthPlace" : "1",
      "birthMonth" : "2"
    }
  }
}
```